# Best Practice: How to update a repeating NSTimer interval after each call to the selector method

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have an `NSTimer` object that I need to repeatedly execute.  The code that it calls is ultimately toggles a setting in my application through 4 various states.  Each time the state changes, I want my interval to change on my timer.  This loop should continue throughout the lifetime of the application.

As far as I can tell, you can not update the `interval` property on an `NSTimer`.  I believe this means that I need to add code to create a new `NSTimer` object each time I toggle my state within my timer code.  The following implementation is what I am thinking:

```
//Consider that in my containing class, there is an NSTimer property, named myTimer.

//My selector method, used by myTimer
-(void) updateState:(NSTimer *) timer
{
    switch (AppState)
    {
    case state_1:
        //Update current state to state_2
        [self setMyTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(updateState:) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        break;
    case state_2:
        //Update current state to state_3
        [self setMyTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(updateState:) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        break;
    case state_3:
        //Update current state to state_4
        [self setMyTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:30.0 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(updateState:) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        break;
    case state_4:
        //Update current state back to state_1
        [self setMyTimer:[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5.0 
                                                          target:self 
                                                        selector:@selector(updateState:) 
                                            userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
        break;
    }
}
```

Is this the most optimal solution or can the creation of all these timers cause any form trouble for my application as it continuously executes?

Also, I have ARC cut on within my project.  In this case, will I still need to destroy the previous `NSTimer` objects?

Comment: If these are the timing intervals you might as well use a repeating 5 second timer and utilize a counter to achieve the longer intervals in state 3 and 1.

Comment: @TriPhoenix i think that may be worth an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> can the creation of all these timers cause any form trouble for my application as it continuously executes?

Not as long as you're managing the memory correctly. Using a synthesized setter will take care of this for you.

> In this case, will I still need to destroy the previous `NSTimer` objects?

Not explicitly. When a non-repeating timer fires, it invalidates itself, and the run loop sends `release` (because it had retained it). If you've got a claim on it, you'll need to release it too, which you do using the setter.

Since none of these timers are repeating, you could drop the ivar and instead use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:`

```
- (void)updateState {

    NSTimeInterval delay = 30;
    switch(AppState)
    {
        case 1: { break; }
        case 2: { delay = 5.0;
                  break; }
        case 3: { break; }
        case 4: { delay = 5.0;
                  break; }
    }

    [self performSelector:@selector(updateState) 
               withObject:nil 
               afterDelay:delay];

}
```

(By the way, I assume you've got `break`s in your real code. You definitely should if you don't.)

Comment: I think I prefer this answer to the other.  Also, yes, I have breaks in my actual code.  My above code was entirely written as an example.  I may leave this one open for a day, or so, just to see if there are any other viable responses.

Comment: Perfectly reasonable; there's nothing wrong with your procedure, so my answer is just a suggestion anyways.